# Stripping Out Characters

Tags: python

I have this code writing to a file;

```
rline = quantity," x ",product, productcost
```

When I read the file, I get this `(8, ' x ', '98456390,Paper Tray,6\r\n', 48)`
I am trying to strip out the characters - brackets, speech marks and\r\n

I am trying to use rline.strip, but I get `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Does anybody know how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, there aren't any brackets or quotes.

The following line of code creates a tuple consisting of `quantity`, the string `" x "` (i.e an x surrounded by a space on each side), `product`, and `productcost`.

```
rline = quantity," x ",product, productcost
```

The parantheses and quotes are a result of representing the entire tuple as a string.

First, you want to convert this to a string by combining all of the elements:

```
joined_string = ''.join(map(str, rline))
```

Next, you want to remove the return characters, `\r\n`:

```
joined_string.replace('\r\n', '')
```

All of that combined:

```
stripped_string = ''.join(map(str, rline)).replace('\r\n', '')
```